# Simplify container iteration using lambdas

Tags: c++, c++11, lambda, iteration

I have two functions, functionA and functionB, that both iterate over a container (std::vector) and perform some work:

```
void functionA() {
  // ...........

  auto meshIterator = mMeshes.begin();
  for (const Renderable &renderable : renderQueue) {
    if (renderable.mMesh == INVALID_MESH_ID) {
      JONS_LOG_ERROR(mLogger, "Renderable MeshID is invalid");
      throw std::runtime_error("Renderable MeshID is invalid");
    }

    if (renderable.mMesh < meshIterator->first->mMeshID)
      continue;

    while (renderable.mMesh > meshIterator->first->mMeshID) {
      meshIterator++;
      if (meshIterator == mMeshes.end()) {
        JONS_LOG_ERROR(mLogger, "Renderable MeshID out of range");
        throw std::runtime_error("Renderable MeshID out of range");
      }
    }

    const bool hasDiffuseTexture =
        renderable.mDiffuseTexture != INVALID_TEXTURE_ID;
    const bool hasNormalTexture =
        renderable.mNormalTexture != INVALID_TEXTURE_ID;

    mGeometryProgram.SetUniformData(
        UnifGeometry(renderable.mWVPMatrix, renderable.mWorldMatrix,
                     hasDiffuseTexture, hasNormalTexture,
                     renderable.mTextureTilingFactor));

    if (hasDiffuseTexture)
      BindTexture2D(OpenGLTexture::TEXTURE_UNIT_GEOMETRY_DIFFUSE,
                    renderable.mDiffuseTexture, mTextures, mLogger);

    if (hasNormalTexture)
      BindTexture2D(OpenGLTexture::TEXTURE_UNIT_GEOMETRY_NORMAL,
                    renderable.mNormalTexture, mTextures, mLogger);

    GLCALL(glBindVertexArray(meshIterator->second));
    GLCALL(glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, meshIterator->first->mIndices,
                          GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0));
    GLCALL(glBindVertexArray(0));
  }

  // ...........
}

void functionB() {
  //....................

  // both containers are assumed to be sorted by MeshID ascending
  auto meshIterator = mMeshes.begin();
  for (const Renderable &renderable : renderQueue) {
    if (renderable.mMesh == INVALID_MESH_ID) {
      JONS_LOG_ERROR(mLogger, "Renderable MeshID is invalid");
      throw std::runtime_error("Renderable MeshID is invalid");
    }

    if (renderable.mMesh < meshIterator->first->mMeshID)
      continue;

    while (renderable.mMesh > meshIterator->first->mMeshID) {
      meshIterator++;
      if (meshIterator == mMeshes.end()) {
        JONS_LOG_ERROR(mLogger, "Renderable MeshID out of range");
        throw std::runtime_error("Renderable MeshID out of range");
      }
    }

    const Mat4 wvp = lightVP * renderable.mWorldMatrix;
    mNullProgram.SetUniformData(UnifNull(wvp));

    GLCALL(glBindVertexArray(meshIterator->second));
    GLCALL(glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, meshIterator->first->mIndices,
                          GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0));
    GLCALL(glBindVertexArray(0));
  }

  // ...............
}
```

They way they iterate over the container is very similiar, but the work they do in the body is very different. I would like to join these two (possibly more in the future) in a single function instead, like this:

```
void DrawModels(const std::function<
    void(const Renderable &renderable)> &preDrawFunc) {
  // both containers are assumed to be sorted by MeshID ascending
  auto meshIterator = mMeshes.begin();
  for (const Renderable &renderable : renderQueue) {
    if (renderable.mMesh == INVALID_MESH_ID) {
      JONS_LOG_ERROR(mLogger, "Renderable MeshID is invalid");
      throw std::runtime_error("Renderable MeshID is invalid");
    }

    if (renderable.mMesh < meshIterator->first->mMeshID)
      continue;

    while (renderable.mMesh > meshIterator->first->mMeshID) {
      meshIterator++;
      if (meshIterator == mMeshes.end()) {
        JONS_LOG_ERROR(mLogger, "Renderable MeshID out of range");
        throw std::runtime_error("Renderable MeshID out of range");
      }
    }

    preDrawFunc(renderable);

    GLCALL(glBindVertexArray(meshIterator->second));
    GLCALL(glDrawElements(GL_TRIANGLES, meshIterator->first->mIndices,
                          GL_UNSIGNED_INT, 0));
    GLCALL(glBindVertexArray(0));
  }
}
```

I reason the std::function provided can be used to perform some arbitrary work depending on the caller, like this:

```
void functionD() {
  auto preDrawRenderable = [&](const Renderable &renderable) {
    const bool hasDiffuseTexture =
        renderable.mDiffuseTexture != INVALID_TEXTURE_ID;
    const bool hasNormalTexture =
        renderable.mNormalTexture != INVALID_TEXTURE_ID;

    mGeometryProgram.SetUniformData(
        UnifGeometry(renderable.mWVPMatrix, renderable.mWorldMatrix,
                     hasDiffuseTexture, hasNormalTexture,
                     renderable.mTextureTilingFactor));

    if (hasDiffuseTexture)
      BindTexture2D(OpenGLTexture::TEXTURE_UNIT_GEOMETRY_DIFFUSE,
                    renderable.mDiffuseTexture, mTextures, mLogger);

    if (hasNormalTexture)
      BindTexture2D(OpenGLTexture::TEXTURE_UNIT_GEOMETRY_NORMAL,
                    renderable.mNormalTexture, mTextures, mLogger);
  };

  DrawModels(preDrawRenderable);
}

void functionE() {
  auto preDrawRenderable = [&](const Renderable &renderable) {
    const Mat4 wvp = lightVP * renderable.mWorldMatrix;
    mNullProgram.SetUniformData(UnifNull(wvp));
  };

  DrawModels(preDrawRenderable);
}
```

My questions:

1) functionD and functionE will both need to run about 60-100 times per seconds. Does using lambda and std::function incur any significant performance penalties? For example, are there any hidden dynamic memory allocation calls or virtual lookups or whatnot that could trash performance? I don't know the overhead of using lambdas and std::function.

2) Is there a better/faster/cleaner alternative than my naive solution?

Comment: The only reasonable way to implement `std::function` is with dynamic memory allocation and a virtual function call. Lambdas do not have that problem.

Comment: @nwp These two lambdas actually don't capture anything (there's nothing for it to capture, despite the `[&]`), so an implementation of `std::function` could avoid memory allocation and simply store a function pointer.

Comment: isnt there? What abot member variables "mGeometryProgram", "mTextures", "mLogger"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
void DrawModels(const std::function< void(const Renderable &renderable)> &preDrawFunc)
```

instead of that, do this:

```
template<class RenderableFunc>
void DrawModels(RenderableFunc&& preDrawFunc)
```

and leave the body unchanged.  Place it where both of the functions you are replacing can see it.

Now the compiler has an easy optimization problem to inline your lambda.

`std::function` is a type erasure object that does magic that will confuse current generation optimizers.  It is not the type of a lambda, it is a type that can convert any lambda or function pointer or invokable object into an internal object and store it for later execution.

A raw lambda is a compiler generated function object with captured variables and a non-`virtual` operaror().  It is much lighter weight.

Comment: Calling the function like this "DrawModels<decltype(preDrawRenderable)>(preDrawRenderable);" gives "You cannot bind an lvalue to an rvalue reference" with VS2013 - why is that?

Comment: @kaiserjohaan bbecause I used a universal reference intended to be deduced via the argument.  If you must pass a type, pass `<decltype(preDrawRenderable) const&>` unless the argument is `move`d in.  But really just let it be deduced.

Answer (score 2):

> Does using lambda and std::function incur any significant performance penalties?

Lambdas are only anonymous functors created in place. So shouldn't be any noticeable performance penalty compared to your own functions/functors.

On the other hand `std::function` applies type erasure, but commonly (This is implementation defined) uses casting and tag dispatching instead of polymorphism. So could be some performance hits compared to a normal function, but these could be negligible. **EDIT:** As Yakk pointed out on his answer, type-erasure could break the compiler ability to inline the function.

> Is there a better/faster/cleaner alternative than my naive solution?

Could be more elemegant to rely on standard algorithms (The `<algorithm>` header), instead of raw loops. That makes the code more readable, but there is no direct performance benefict.

Note that some advises I have written here could be viewed as a bit subjective. Like in any performance-related question, don't rely on "common sense", measure and do performance profilings. For example, as I said writting code based on algorithms clearifies the code, but could not lead into direct performance benefits. This depends heavily on the context, so just profile.